# How to stop vim from splitting horizontally when opening a new file?

Tags: vim

Usually when I open a file in Vim when there's already one open Vim opens the file in a whole new... buffer? Screen thing? In other words, it takes up the full vim client area so that I have to `:bn` through to see the next file, which I prefer. But sometimes when I open a file Vim decides to split the window horizontally and put it in one of those horizontal buffer things.

When does it decide to split the window as opposed to giving me the whole thing? How can I prevent that behavior? And perhaps most important, what is the name for that kind of behavior so I can do better searches in the future?

Comment: well how do you open files? `vim -o file1 file2`? could be an issue that you type a capital `O`. Well the name of the split feature is split (`:h split`)

Comment: `But sometimes when I open a file Vim decides to...`  please define "sometimes". also, `When does it decide to split the window ...?` when we let vim do so.

Comment: `what is the name for that kind of behavior` See `:help windows.txt`

Comment: Doktor OSWaldo: Boy, was my question poorly phrased. The only ways I ever open files are on the command line with no flags, e.g. `vim foo.go bar.go` and from within I only use `e: foo.go`. It is the latter in which  I have these problems.

Comment: Matt, thanks for the obvious (yet heretofore unknown to me) help reference!

Comment: If youre only using `:e`, it could be a spurious autocommand. Try with `vim —clean`

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from `:help window`:

```
A buffer is an in-memory text of a file
A window is a viewport of a buffer
```

Buffers are enumerated. When you run `:bufnext` or `:bn`, you go to the next buffer; you can also use `:b<num>` to go to a specific buffer, say `:b2` to go to buffer 2. You can get the list of buffers with `:ls`.

When you `:split` or `:vsplit`, you open a new window, i.e. a new viewport for a buffer. You can have two windows show the same buffer, and so on.

Also, a tabpage is a collection of buffers; open a new tab with `:tabnew` and cycle through them with `gt` and `gT` to go forward and backward respectively.

I highly recommend you read the helpfile; it's all there.